# "Chamfered" Routing in Eagle

Tags: rf, pcb-design, eaglecad

I need to create the following trace in Eagle but I can't work out how to make it go from one width to another across a set distance like below.

[image]

Comment: This is normally called a *taper*. A chamfer is when the outer edge of a corner is trimmed back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to make a trace with a gradual smooth linear change in width like that in Eagle.
(edit: Altium allows some control over the shape of the transition region between two traces, which in Altium is called [teardrop](https://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Enhanced+Teardrop+Control).  Thank you @Mario, for this insight.)

It's possible to approximate this with a trace consisting of 2 segments with different widths.  But then the transition "ramps" are going to be circular, rather than linear.

It's possible, however, to create geometry exactly like that with a polygon copper pour.

Comment: In Altium they are called teardrops.

Comment: @Mario  Thank you for this insight!  I have updated my answer.